# Is there a way to download files from server automatically?

Tags: javascript, java, file-transfer

I'm working on an old webapp written in Java. I need a button (HTML) which automatically downloads a pdf from server to a specific client-side directory with no other user interaction. I can run javascript via the browser. I'm really uncomfortable doing this, I'm not really used to JS, Java and HTML. I was thinking about a copy() script to get the file server side and "paste" it client side, but I'm concerned that won't work with tomcat. I've already installed an SSH server on the same machine and I can basically install whatever it's necessary.

As you can see, the program is written in Java (server side) and I can use system.out statement to run html and javascript client side. To me it's pretty confusing, but it's an old software another guy wrote before leaving the company and I can't re-write all of the code, so here we go. Thank you all for the precious help!

```
out.println(""

+ "<script>"
    + "function copy()"
    + "{"
    + "  var object, f;"
    + "  object = new ActiveXObject(\"Scripting.FileSystemObject\");"
    + "  f = oggetto.copy(\"" + sourceURL + "\", \"" + targetDir + "\");"
    + "}"
    + "</script>"
);
```

Comment: You can't force download for security reasons. It should be always to user to choose what to do. You can forget [Active​XObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/ActiveXObject), _Warning: This object is a Microsoft extension and is supported in Internet Explorer only, not in Windows 8.x Store apps._

Comment: You should clarify who needs this functionality and what server side techologies and frameworks you use. Otherwise this question is very generic and hard to answer. If only you or a small group of people need access to these files you could install samba on the server and allow access to a share.

Comment: Both the server and the clients run on windows. Everything is on a private network and just few people requested that functionality, so security is not a concern at the moment. The application is written in Java and runs on a tomcat server, clients can log with a basic username/password authentication and are presented html pages with very basic interaction capabilities. Both Javascript and HTML are presented in the form of out.println() commands in java.